# Yii: Design-By-Contract with PHPUnit

Tags: php, yii, phpunit, require-once, design-by-contract

Why does the call of PHPUnit in the class CTestCase works:

```
require_once('PHPUnit/Autoload.php');
....

PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertNotNull($object);
```

But if I call it the same way in a file of components directory it shows me:

```
require_once(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Even if I add the same imports as in CTestCase it doesn't work.

```
require_once('PHPUnit/Util/Filesystem.php'); // workaround for PHPUnit <= 3.6.11
require_once('PHPUnit/Autoload.php');
spl_autoload_unregister('phpunit_autoload');
Yii::registerAutoloader('phpunit_autoload');
```

It shows me:

```
require_once(PHPUnit/Util/Filesystem.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I am using namespaces and want to use [design-by-contract](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/api.html).

I really hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/36320-phpunit-not-working-with-yii-ctestcase-phpunit-autoload-not-found/) I found the solution for my problem. 
Here is the code to enable Design-By-Contract asserts of PHPUnit in Yii Controllers and Helper Classes.

```
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
require_once('PHPUnit/Autoload.php');
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you surf inside the Frameworks/test/CTestCase.php, then you will find like this,

```
require_once('PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php');
require_once('PHPUnit/Util/Filesystem.php'); // workaround for PHPUnit <= 3.6.11

spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
require_once('PHPUnit/Autoload.php');
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload')); // put yii's autoloader at the end

if (in_array('phpunit_autoload', spl_autoload_functions())) { // PHPUnit >= 3.7 'phpunit_autoload' was obsoleted
    spl_autoload_unregister('phpunit_autoload');
    Yii::registerAutoloader('phpunit_autoload');
}
```

I think, it will help you to understand your problem.

Comment: Hi, I added the file imports of CTestCase to my question. But I can't solve my problem. Is it possible to solve it?